# Optimizacion rendimiento Server mysql

Tags: mysql

Me gustaria que me orientaran como configurar el servidor mysql para que use la mayor cantidad de recursos disponibles. El motor por defecto es innobd...es un servicio dedicado en un VPS....solo esta mysql server.
Los procesadores son

- root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name".
- model name   : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz.
- model name   : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
- root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-sfo2-01:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "cpu cores"
- cpu cores    : 1
- cpu cores    : 1

Lo que deseo saber es como optimizarlo para usar un porcentaje alto de los cpu y memoria.....un 80% de ambos. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Podrías subir la configuración actual de tu Servidor MySQL. Además, puedes correr un test con [MySQL Tuner](https://www.solutein.com/acelerar-y-optimizar-mysql-con-mysql-tuner/amp/) y subir los resultados, ya que sin saber lo que tienes es dificil decir qué podrías mejorar. Por otro lado, tu pregunta no parece relacionada con un problema de programación. Tal vez puedas buscar información o realizar tu pregunta en [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com). Aunque es un sitio en inglés. Saludos

Comment: Lo que deseo es saber, es que si cuento con el hardware descrito anteriormente como podria configurar el servidor mysql para sacar el mejor provecho de la misma usando un motor Innodb.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con sacar provecho? Edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en tu archivo `.cnf` de MySQL, para saber lo que tienes y tal vez se te pueda decir algo. Además, has el test que te sugerí. Más allá del hardware que tienes, no se puede saber cómo sacarle provecho sin que digas cómo lo tienes actualmente configurado. Igual, verifica en la página que te sugerí. Seguro allí encuentras tips para lograr lo que intentas. Saludos

Comment: Eso lo he hecho. La razon por la cual no subo el archivo cnf es para saber si a partir de solo conocer los datos anteriores se puede crear un template con los parametros que generalmente deberian configurarse para hacer que mysql use el 80% tanto de la memoria ram y del CPU....